# Highcharts tooltips not accessible for certain data points

Tags: highcharts

Sometimes it is very difficult to get the Highcharts Javascript charting library to show a tool tip for certain data points. For example, try to show the tooltip of the data point at 50,50 on the below link. It is very difficult to get it to show, and it flickers a lot. Does anyone know about some workaround?

http://highcharts.com/jsbin/ogixaz/2/edit

I tried it with an update-to-date Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: It looks good form me. Or maybe I didn't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the tooltip at 50,50 flickers is because the tooltip is being drawn over the point. The points to the left and right allow room for the tooltip to be drawn to the side. The reason the middle one can't be drawn to the side is that the chart is small, and the toolip is big.

Some ideas to help this situation:
1. Making the tooltip smaller.
2. Make the chart bigger (try making the right hand side bigger in your example).
3. Use the highcharts tooltip.positioner function to place the tooltip somewhere else.

Comment: 1&2: yes, thanks. we're using big tool-tips with rich info, so these won't work all that well. 3: I'm OK with the tool-tip position, where it overlaps the data point. I just want it to show the tool-tip for the data-point closest to my mouse pointer.

Comment: It seems as if it remembers the last series for which it showed a tool-tip, and tries to stick to that series for the next tool-tip to display. Even if the mouse pointer only touches the line and not the data-point. The behavior I'm after is to show the tool-tip for the data-point closest to the mouse pointer.

Comment: Here's one with smaller tool-tips. It's still difficult to get it to show the tool-tip for 50,50.  http://highcharts.com/jsbin/ogixaz/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
 //...

 plotOptions:{
        series:{
          stickyTracking:true;
        }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have to say that i looked at your embeded example and understood exactly what you meant,
**but** after moveing your code into the jsFiddle and setting  the property `shared:true` (in the tooltip object), it works fine. check it...  http://jsfiddle.net/yoav_barnea/LFvVy/2/

**the important part is the property `shared:true` :**

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return '<b style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;">Some very long title</b><br/>' + this.x + ":" + this.y + " <br/>and some<br/> extra stuff<br/>line<br/>line";
    },
    useHTML: true,
    shared:true
},
```

**UPDATE 2:**

as for your other problem on getting the costom `c` property (that you mentioned in the comment...), the solution for that is to fix your code inside the **formatter function** into somthing like this: `return ... this.points[0].point.c`

(again, this was a new issue, not related to the first one of flickering tooltip...)

Comment: is it possible that you are trying that in an old version/environment.

Comment: have you run it on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: Thanks, the 'shared' seems to help! Unfortunately, it looses any custom properties of the data (c in the example). That does work when not using shared tool tips.  http://jsfiddle.net/jZqVF/

Comment: in order to get the value of `c` property, you need to fix your code inside the **formatter function** into this: `this.points[0].point.c`

Comment: Thanks, my bad, I overlooked it in the documentation albeit it is literally mentioned.