# Tooltip to display middle points in a series in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

I have a series of points under a single series and I want the tooltip to display all the points in the series but my tooltip displays the top and bottom points selected and does not display the remaining points through the tool tip.How to fix this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=7IfUNtFkAE

In the above fiddle,I have the tooltip displaying values for the top and bottom points for apple series ,hovered over in the fiddle.How will i make it such that middle points are also displayed when i hover over them ?

Comment: Simplified "hover over" test case: http://jsfiddle.net/X5ztK/
Some points in apple series cannot be highlighted/selected.

Comment: Related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247201/highcharts-tooltips-not-accessible-for-certain-data-points

Comment: jsFiddle by user2844540 doesn't work for me. Example by @Ivan Chau: Highcharts require one point for specific x.

Comment: @Paweł Fus What does that mean? x and y is defined in data though not sorted beforehand.

Comment: Data like this: `[[0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 13]]` (three points have x=0) isn't proper for Highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

- As Paweł Fus pointed out in the comment, the data is not well prepared for highcharts.

  So I have converted it from basic line chart to **Scatter plot with line**.

  Scatter plot with line
  http://jsfiddle.net/S8wzF/1/ OR http://jsfiddle.net/S8wzF/2/

  Reference:
  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter
  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-regression

---

- Original fiddle with highcharts usage issues

  - Add [`useHTML`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.useHTML) for tooltip when HTML formatting is in use.
  - [`shared`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared) is not needed and thus return statement of formatter is modified accordingly.

    ```
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + 'fruit_id' + ': ' + this.point.fruit_id + '<br/>' + 'Values' + ': ' + this.point.y + '<br/>' + 'Mean' + ': ' + this.point.mean + '<br/>' + 'Median' + ': ' + this.point.median + '<br/>' + 'Min' + ': ' + this.point.min + '<br/>' + 'Max' + ': ' + this.point.max + '<br/>'
        }
    }
    ```

---

- Original code contains Javascript problems (Unrelated to highcharts)

  The series add data incorrectly as it is inside the loop.

  Put this segment of code **outside** "for loop".

  ```
  series.push({
      data: data,
      type: 'line',
      color: '#000',
      marker: {
          symbol: 'circle'
      },
      showInLegend: false
  });
  ```

Comment: :It still is not working yet :(.The above fiddle that you sent.Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Basic idea is to use Scatter plot. I'm trying to make a nearly working demo.

Comment: Thanks ivan.the problem is i don want to hardcode like you had done inside the series.I want to use an array initially that has hardcoded values and then use it inside the series.

Comment: According your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/S8wzF/2/ And you should post your original version of fiddle to your post to benefit others.